# foldr with 4 arguments?

Tags: haskell

I am struggling to understand why this code taken from the [haskell.org exercise page](https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/Solutions/5)  typechecks (and works as a list reversal function):

```
myReverse :: [a] -> [a]
myReverse xs = foldr (\x fId empty -> fId (x : empty)) id xs []
```

My first point of confusion is that foldr accepts 3 arguments, not 4 :

```
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

so I am guessing that `myReverse` is equivalent to:

```
myReverse xs = foldr ((\x fId empty -> fId (x : empty)) id) xs []
```

but then this should not work either since in the lambda, `x` is a list element rather than a function ...

Comment: Because `foldr ... xs` returns a function, which takes a list and then populates it with elements from `xs`. Initially this function is `id` (which means that it doesn't change the list). Then each `foldr` iteration modifies the function: it adds the current element and then performs the rest (i.e. adds already seen elements).

Comment: Essentially, any function `f :: ... -> ... -> b` accepts an arbitrarily large number of arguments. This is because `b` can be `A1 -> ... -> An -> T` making it possible to apply the function "result of `f`" to `n` additional arguments. For instance, `id :: b -> b` allows `id (+) 3 4`. That being said, I regard "`foldr` with >3 arguments" as a sort of antipattern, since IMO explicit recursion would be more clear. Above the `empty` argument is not always bound to the empty list, creating more confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of it this way. Every function accepts exactly one argument. It may return another function (that accepts one argument). The thing that looks like a multi-argument call

```
f a b c
```

is actually parsed as

```
((f a) b) c
```

that is, a chain of single-argument function applications. A function type

```
f :: a -> b -> c -> d
```

can be decomposed to

```
f :: a -> (b -> (c -> d))
```

i.e. a function returning a function returning a function. We usually regard it as a function of three arguments. But can it accept more than three? Yes, if `d` happens to be another function type.

This is exactly what happens with your `fold` example. The function that you pass as the first argument to `foldr` accepts three arguments, which is exactly the same as accepting two arguments and returning another function. Now the (simplified) type of `foldr` is

```
(a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

but if you look at the first argument of it, you see it's a function of three arguments. Which is, as we have seen, exactly the same as a function that acceora two arguments and returns a function. So the `b` happens to be a function type. Since `b` is also the the return tuoe of `foldr` when applied to three arguments

```
foldr (\x fId empty -> fId (x : empty)) id
```

and it's a function, it can now be applied to another argument

```
(foldr (\x fId empty -> fId (x : empty)) id xs) []
```

I let you figure out what `b` actually is.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the variables naming is atrocious. I always use `r` for the second argument to a foldr's reducer function, as a mnemonic for the "recursive result". "`empty`" is too overloaded with meaning; it is better to use some neutral name so it is easier to see what it is without any preconceived notions:

```
myReverse :: [a] -> [a]
myReverse xs = foldr (\x r n -> r (x : n)) id xs []
```

By virtue of foldr's definition,

```
foldr f z (x:xs)  ===  f x (foldr f z xs)
```

i.e.

```
myReverse [a,b,c,...,z]
     = foldr (\x r n -> r (x : n)) id [a,b,c,...,z] []
     = (\x r n -> r (x : n)) a (foldr (\x r n -> r (x : n)) id [b,c,...,z]) []
     = (\x r n -> r (x : n)) 
         a 
           (foldr (\x r n -> r (x : n)) id [b,c,...,z])
             []
     = let { x = a
           ; r = foldr (\x r n -> r (x : n)) id [b,c,...,z]
           ; n = []
           }
       in r (x : n)
     = foldr (\x r n -> r (x : n)) id [b,c,...,z] (a : [])
     = foldr (\x r n -> r (x : n)) id [b,c,...,z] [a]
     = ....
     = foldr (\x r n -> r (x : n)) id [c,...,z] (b : [a])
     = foldr (\x r n -> r (x : n)) id [c,...,z] [b,a]
     = ....
     = foldr (\x r n -> r (x : n)) id [] [z,...,c,b,a]
     = id [z,...,c,b,a]
```

I hope this illustration makes it clearer what is going on there. The extra argument is expected by the reducer function, which is pushed into action by `foldr` ... resulting in the operational equivalent of

```
     = foldl (\n x -> (x : n)) [] [a,b,c,...,z]
```

As it turns out, `myReverse` implementation is using the equivalence

```
foldl (flip f) n xs  ===  foldr (\x r -> r . f x) id xs n
```